# How to create a class in laravel and instanciate it with jquery and ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new in laravel and I want to create a class in larevel containing  a static attribute in order to use them in  views and controler:

 
 I want to crate a class like this :

```
    class Info{ 
     static $id;
     static $temps;
     public function setID($id)
      {
           this.id=$id;
      }
     public getId($id)
      {
         return this->id;}
}
```

- first is their any way to do it in laravel if yes how and where should I put it?
- how can I instanciate it?
- is theire any wany to instanciate it in script using Jquery and ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent controller class, sample:

```
class Parent extends Controller { 
 public $id;
 public $temps;
 public function setID($id)
 {
    $this->id = $id;
 }
 public getId($id)
 {
    return $this->id;
 }
```

}

And every create a class controller, just call that class. Sample:

```
class FooClass extends Parent {}
```